# Assign header to a query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
select abc from table1 union select def from table2
```

I want the results to be clubbed together as a different header.

I am trying

```
Select * as diff (select abc from table1 union select def from table2)
```

What should be the query so that the result is clubbed in a third column header diff.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to have a custom column name in the outer query.
You can do that by specifically referencing the column which you would like to rename.
Here is an example:

```
create table t (c varchar(10));
create table t2 (c2 varchar(10));

insert into t values ('abc');
insert into t2 values ('def');

select s.c as t
from (
    select c 
    from t
  union 
    select c2 
    from t2
) s;
```

Results in:

```
 t
---
abc
def
```

For reference see: http://sqlize.com/7RKZw41Hqx

Answer (score 1):

just use the header alias in first select:

```
select abc as diff from table1 union 
select def from table2
```